# Image upload options for website users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload

I want to be able to provide my website users with the ability to upload a profile picture. What are my options? What is the best way to do this? I would need to be able to limit the image size, crop / resize the image so that I can display thumbnails of the image. The website is written using Ruby on Rails

Comment: This [Railscast on using Paperclip and cropping images](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images) sounds perfect for you!

Answer (score 1):

In alternate plugin to manage your upload file is [carrierwave](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The PaperClip plugin is pretty much the new hotness (standard):

http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

It supports different image processors but we use ImageScience. RMagick leaks memory

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others recommendation of Paperclip for handling any kind of upload.

However for profile pictures in particular, if you are storing your user's email addresses you might like to consider using [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/), as StackOverflow does, to effectively "outsource" this functionality and let your users maintain consistent avatars among all the sites they use.

Comment: how i can use this two method Gravtar or Self-image upload system too.